# How can I run a program from my C# program in hidden mode?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to run a program in c#, silently (no window, trace, of the program being executed). How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the use case here? I'm tempted to jump to "write a service"

Comment: Microsoft Office Word interop / hidden print

Answer (score 1):

if you want run the whole project in hidden mode and it is a console application, just go to Project Properties and set Output type to Windows Application. thats it.

If you want to run some other program inside your main program in hidden mode you may use following code.

```
        string cmdText = "/c " + cmdStr;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;           
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdText;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.Start();
```

the option which hide your console window is proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;, and cmdStr is the command or programg you want to exeute.

Comment: You can set proc.StartInfo.FileName  to path of any program to run it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run with a program with trace(notification icon in right bottom) means use  NotifyIcon(In toolbox list is available) or if you want to run without any notification you need to go for service. This is the best guide for creating first service program[Windows Service](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/creating-windows-service-in-c-or.html)